# FreeNas HDD slot info into the disk bay

Tags: freebsd, nas

**diskinfo -v /dev/da14** gives an output
*id1,enc@n500304801727e03d/type@0/**slot@5**/elmdesc@**Slot04** # Physical path*

Which one is actually the slot number of the disk14 in the disk bay.

Comment: give a try to `camcontrol devlist`

Comment: Shows only hdd info, nothing from disk bay.